# Return object of subclass type from parent class automatically

Tags: swift, oop

So basically I have a parent class called Model with the following function

```
static func allModels(complete: @escaping ([Model]) -> Void) {
    var models = [Model]()
    DatabaseHelper.firebase.child(getDB()).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            for id in data.keys {
                if var modelData = data[id] as? [String: Any] {
                    modelData[MasterField.id] = id
                    let model = self.init(data: modelData)
                    models.append(model)
                }
            }
        }
        complete(models)
    }
}
```

It works great but here's the thing. I have several subclasses of Model such as "School", "Person" etc. For each subclass I have to do something like this

```
static func all(complete: @escaping ([School]) -> Void) {
    super.allModels { (models) in
        complete(models as! [School])
    }
}
```

All it does is call the method and cast the result to its own type. It's really annoying having to do this for every method for every subclass. Is there a way to do this automatically from the parent class? So calling `School.all()` would invoke `Model.all()` but return a School while `Person.all()` would also invoke `Model.all()` but return a Person.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of all that repetition with `Generics`.

```
static func allModels<T>(complete: @escaping ([T]) -> Void)
    {
        var models = [T]()
        DatabaseHelper.firebase.child(getDB()).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                for id in data.keys {
                    if var modelData = data[id] as? [String: Any] {
                        modelData[MasterField.id] = id
                        let model = self.init(data: modelData)
                        models.append(model as! T)
                    }
                }
            }
            complete(models)
        }
    }
```

It's worth noting that if the type inferred by the completion closure is different from the class you're calling `allModels()` from, the forced downcast (`as!`) will crash.

Comment: Using your code I get the following error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Comment: Trying to call it with this code: School.allModels { (school) in
            for school in schools {
                print(school.name)
            }
        }

Comment: If I add static func allModels<T: Model> then that error goes away but I get a new one. "value of type model has no member name"